# how can I change numer of items in sp2010 list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, branding

How can I change the number of items in a SharePoint 2010 list in master page ? Like the images below: [image]

Comment: This looks like a list view. what it has to do with the master page?

Comment: I want to be a change in the standard view and master page. have an idea?

Comment: There is no global setting, the default is hardcoded, Query WebParts default to 10 items, ListViews to 30

Comment: What changes in the standard view can show the number of items to display in this way?

Comment: There is a setting for each view that allows to set the number of items per page! Is this what you are looking for?